# Validate data before submitting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation

I'm new to programming and C#, I'm trying to make a small Electronic Voting System, How can I make the votes invalid when the voter votes an excess number of candidates. For example: The user voted 7 candidates instead of 6 in councilor position, how can I make his vote invalid or doesn't let him to submit his votes till he make it 6.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Frm_voteview : Form
{
    string userid;
    public Frm_voteview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
    }
    public Frm_voteview(string userid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       new Frm_Login().Show();
       this.Hide();
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }




    private void Frm_voteview_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Frm_voteview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        if (MessageBox.Show("Confirm and View your Votes?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Voting Successful", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE candidate SET cTally = cTally + 1 where cName like @cname or cName like @vName", con))
            {

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", cb_president.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vName", cb_vpresident.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            foreach (object item in lb_councilor.SelectedItems)
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE candidate SET cTally = cTally + 1 where cName like @coname", con))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coname", (item as DataRowView)["cName"].ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine((item as DataRowView)["cName"].ToString());
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE voters SET isVoted = 1 where userName like @uname", con))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", userid );

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            this.Close();
            new Form4().Show();
            this.Hide();


        }
        else
        {
            this.Activate();
        }   
    }

    private void Frm_voteview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter2.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter1.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate);

    }

    private void dgv_councilor_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dgv_councilor_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Frm_voteview_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.VotingSystemv2ConnectionString);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter2.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet7.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter1.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet5.candidate);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.candidateTableAdapter.Fill(this.votingSystemv2DataSet4.candidate);
        con.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form9().Show();
    }

    private void cb_president_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lb_councilor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Side note: please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to C#.

Okay, few things.  First off, the answer to your question?  Take a look at your line of code:

```
foreach (object item in lb_councilor.SelectedItems)
```

... what this is doing is looping through a collection of items that have been selected.  Well, try typing in lb_councilor.SelectedItems - and hopefully your intellisense in VisualStudio will tell you what it is (probably something like an IEnumerable or such.)

[That's one of the good tricks with VS - typing in a variable/object/whatever and seeing what intellisense brings up about it.]

Well, the good news is, stuff like IEnumerable has a Count method.  So your problem might be as easy as:

```
if (lb_councilor.SelectedItems.Count != 6)
{
    // uh oh.  Better stop them.
```

Okay, now that that's out of the way, here's some additional things:

- Make sure you name every object that finds its way into code.  candidateTableAdapter1, votingSystemv2DataSet5, label5, button1, Form9 - you're going to make some other dev's life a nightmare if you hand them code that's referencing a bunch of default-named items.
- Don't use 'object' when looping through a foreach unless you can help it.  Here's what your code is doing

  ```
  foreach (object something in somegroup)
  {
      use(something as DataRowView);
  }
  ```

... aka, you're casting 'something' as an object... but then right afterwards you're using it as an DataRowView.  You might as well do:

```
    foreach (DataRowView something in somegroup)
```

Either that, or at least do something like this:

```
    foreach (object something in somegroup)
    {
        if (something is DataGridView)
        {
            // your code is safe from an unexpected data type now
            use(something as DataGridView);
```